# Angular 2: Smart component passing in data to Presentation component

Tags: angular

I have set up where I have a smart component that `ngOnInit` uses a service to call out to a Rest API to fetch an object of data.

That data is passed into the presentation (child) component through an `@Input()` property.

In the presentation component, I need to repack the data into a bit of a different model so that it fits into the 3rd party component I am using for presentation.

I am not 100% how to deal with that fact that in the `ngOnInit` of the *presentatioin* component, the passed in `@Input` property is still `undefined`. Since the actual data is a Rest API call, the parent (smart) component will only get it in the `subscribe`'s observer, i.e., asynchronously.

How do I hook this up together such that I am not trying to manipulate an `undefined` object, but wait until it's actually there in the presentation component?

I guess, I can always link the presentation component to the smart parent component through `@ViewChild` and then introduce a public method on the presentation component like `showData(data)`, but I am wondering what the best practice is here.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter, https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Comment: Use the ngOnChanges instead

Comment: Can you provide your code? Seems like your setup is different than mine.

Comment: @DeborahK Would this be better than using @ViewChild. For some reason I thought that method fired on any event in the browser... It doesn't. However, I'd still have to put an `if` statement in there to make sure it's right property. Curious what the best practice is here.

Comment: This scenario is the entire purpose of the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook. From the docs provided in the link above: "Angular calls its ngOnChanges() method whenever it detects changes to input properties of the component (or directive)." So its purpose in life is to wait for the data to be set and then react accordingly. And yes, you will still need an if statement if the value may be initialized.

Comment: @DeborahK, thank you. Your time is much appreciated! But why, *in this scenario* is it better to use onChanges instead of simply calling the presentation component's API method as I described at the end? This is what I am doing now, but wanted to know if there is a better way. Introducing another `if` statement into the mix is fine, but for what benefit? Just curious as to your thoughts on this. Feel free to copy/paste your current comments into an answer and I'll give you credit for it. Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing the full requirements or completely understanding your solution, it's hard to comment further. But I often go for the plan that if I have to do "x" and Angular has a well-defined technique for doing "x", I'm normally going to do it that way even through way "y" may also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the child component you have to listen for changes to the input. Once the `data` input has changed and has data. You can then repack it into another property.

In this example the input `data` gets assigned to `repacked`. Notice the `*ngIf` in the template to prevent the use of the third party stuff until the data is ready.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child',
    tempalte: '<div *ngIf="repacked"><!-- third-party stuff --></div>'
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
   @Input()
   public data: Object;

   public repacked: Object;

   public ngChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      if('data' in changes) {
           this.repack(changes['data'].currentValue);
      }
   }

   private repack(data: Object) {
       if(data) {
          this.repacked = data; // <-- do repacking work here
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is actually quite some answers online for this already. Have a look at https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components

I reviewed your case and although it's hard to understand without knowing exactly what you do. I solved this by initializing my variable in the Smart Component:

```
private apiData: Array = [];
```

Using *ngIf in my template, and then repacking the data in the child if I have the data:

```
@Input('apiData') apiData: <any>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.repack();
}

repack(): void {
    // here is the part that prevents errors
    if(! this.apiData) return;

    // repack logic here
}
```

However @ThinkingMedia answer is likely the more correct one in your case.

Comment: This won't work. Your `apiData` at the time of calling repack() is `undefined` and nothing will be done because of the check. It won't magically call `repack` again after that.